# Tinymce auto set readonly if the textarea has readonly

Tags: jquery, tinymce

How would I set tinymce to automatically set the editor as [readonly](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/read_only_mode.php) if the `textarea` already has the `attr("readonly")`

Comment: why do you want to add readonly if its already have readonly

Comment: @jhonraymos, He has already set the textarea to readonly.  Now he wants tinymce to treat it that way too.

Comment: ohh i am not familiar with tinymce

Comment: See answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/35982854/2614103 for TinyMCE v4.3.x

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A more general solution might be

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    setup: function(ed) {
        if($('#'+ed.id).attr('readonly'))
            ed.settings.readonly = true;
    }
});
```

This will work for all textareas without you having to specify any ids. In addition it will actually set the editor to readonly mode, and not only prevent editing.

Comment: God! Finally I find a solution!

Answer (score 4):

In case you have the following textarea

```
<textarea id="my_textarea_id" readonly="readonly">Some content here.</textarea>
```

you may save the knowledge of having a readonly attribute to a variable:

```
var readonly = $("textarea#my_textarea_id").attr("readonly") ? 1 : 0;
```

Now the tinymce init function. We choose mode `none` to init the editor later.

```
tinyMCE.init({
        theme : "advanced",
        mode: 'none',
        readonly : readonly,
        ...
});
```

Here, you can init your editor instance using the id of your textarea

```
tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, "my_textarea_id");
```

Your editor instance will be initialized as readonly.

Comment: Dude you should write a book with all the modifications you know on tinymce, I would definitely buy it. Their documentation is hard to understand, well for me: e.g: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Command_identifiers and http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.execCommand and you search for: 'mceAddControl' returns nothing. I guess its easy to find, if you know exactly what you are looking for

Comment: thanks, but my knowledge is far from letting me write a book about it :)  Finding the right thing in the documentation can be tricky sometimes. You will find the hint to mceAddControl in the description of the configuration parameter mode: http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration:mode

Answer (score 2):

if do not wish to apply tinyMCE to the readonly fields use `class="readonly"` then

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    editor_deselector: "readonly"
});
```

the textareas with readonly class will be ignored

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the HTML will be displayed if I use a standard textarea. I need tinymce to display this in a iframe

Answer (score 0):

if you what set readOnly mode of tinyMce you should use tinyMCE API.
so you can set read only:

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme : "advanced",
        readonly : 1
});
```

If you want to set only value "readonly" for textarea, so please note that tinyMce has own wrapper for this field, and native field(from html) - set as hidden field, so it is useless set any attribute for one

Comment: this would work. problem here is that he wants to make this setting dependant on the class of his textarea - see my solution for this

Answer (score 0):

I have several tiny mce's and some of them have class="nonEditableMCE" and some have class="editableMCE". If that is the case, you can have two inits and this is working. It is much simpler when Id's are dynamic to use class selector.

```
tinymce.init({
        selector: ".nonEditableMCE",
        height: 200,
        statusbar: false,
       readonly : 1

    });

    tinymce.init({
        selector: ".editableMCE",
        height: 200,
        statusbar: false,
        readonly: 0

    });
```