# make readonly/disable tinymce textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce, wysiwyg

I need to disable or make readonly a tinymce textarea at runtime.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Use the configuration parameter [readonly](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3areadonly)

```
tinyMCE.init({
        ...
        theme : "advanced",
        readonly : 1
});
```

Here is a [link to a demo](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/read_only_mode.php).

**Update**:
What you can do to prevent users from editing content in your editor is to set the contenteditable attribute of the editors iframe body to false:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

Comment: thanks,but I need to do this at runtime, not during initilization

Comment: in this case have a look at the following SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946391/set-tinymce-editor-param-after-initialized

Answer (score 57):

From version 4.3.x on you can use code below for readonly mode

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setMode('readonly');
```

and for design mode:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.setMode('design');
```

Comment: This also appears to be the only working solution in 4.3.x as other suggestions simply do not work.

Comment: Problem is that it doesn't only disable editing but all plugins as well, including Preview and see the source code

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. It's also the cleanest solution presented.

Comment: Great! You can also use `tinyMCE.get('editor_ID').setMode('readonly');`

Comment: this code is usable in case we have only 1 tinyemc field on the page. I m having 2  Textarea it works for only 1 text area and another one is editable

Comment: @blazetango check the comment above yours

Comment: @grajsek I can explain what I meant

Answer (score 26):

IF you only have one editor, this works:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

If you have multiple editors, you have to select them by the id of the textarea:

```
tinyMCE.get('textarea_id').getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

Comment: Despite of the textarea gets disabled, it still can be modified with the toolbar, or bt selecting all the content whit double click

Answer (score 16):

Thariama's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13881837/990642) will set all TinyMCE textareas on the page to readonly.

The best solution I've found was [posted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18056638/990642) by Magnar Myrtveit which will set fields to readonly that have the readonly attribute. Here is the code:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    setup: function(ed) {
        if ($('#'+ed.id).prop('readonly')) {
            ed.settings.readonly = true;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way I found (this is via tinymce-react, but should work with js as well), is to set the control to disabled. Using tinymce 5.2.

```
                <Editor 
                initialValue={details}
                disabled = {true}
                init = {{
                    height: 300,
                    menubar: false,
                    toolbar: false,
                    readonly: true
                }}/>
```

Comment: Yeah, the React version is a little different. The docs mention `readonly` getting overridden: https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/integrations/react/#init

Answer (score 2):

To disable you can call this command:

```
tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceToggleEditor', true, tinymceId);
```

And to again enable the editor you can again call this command.

'**mceToggleEditor**' command toggles the WYSIWYG mode on or off by displaying or hiding the textarea and editor instance. This is not the same thing as mceAddControl or mceRemoveControl because the instance is still there and uninitialized, so this method is faster.

Link for above command: 
http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:Command_identifiers

Answer (score 2):

For the latest 5.x version, use

```
editor.mode.set('readonly')
```

and

```
editor.mode.set('design')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see this answer here by @rioted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34764607/1827960.

I used it to come up with this solution:

```
tinymce.settings = $.extend(tinymce.settings, { readonly: 1 });
tinymce.EditorManager.editors.forEach(function (editor) {
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceRemoveEditor', false, editor.id);
    //tinymce.EditorManager.editors = [];
    tinymce.EditorManager.execCommand('mceAddEditor', false, editor.id);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
this.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
```

take look at full solution,, my server side is `Asp.net MVC`

```
 setup: function (ed) {
        ed.on('init', function () {
            this.execCommand("fontSize", false, "17px");
            $("html,body").scrollTop(0);
            @if (ViewBag.desableEdit != null && ViewBag.desableEdit == true)
            {
                <text>
                    this.getBody().setAttribute('contenteditable', false);
                </text>
            }

        });
```

anather way to do it if you have `server side condition` which will be removed in the returned HTML

```
 tinymce.init({
    selector: ... ,
    ....
    @if (ViewBag.desableEditExseptExportNumber != null && ViewBag.desableEditExseptExportNumber == true)
    {
         <text>
              readonly: 1,
         </text>
    }
    language: 'ar',
    ....});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
getInit(): any
{
    const result = {
        base_url: baseUrl,
        menubar: false,
        branding: false,
        height: '500',
        selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
        toolbar: false,
        statusbar: false,
        readonly: true,
        setup: function(ed)
        {
            ed.settings.readonly = true;
        }
    };
    return result;
}
```

Comment: When you post an answer for a 8-year old question, please explain it in a few words and describe why it's different from the others.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this code line helps in others browsers using iframes.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getBody().contenteditable = false
```

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

That works for ASP.NET MVC Razor

```
readonly: @(Model.Readonly ? "true" : "false")
```

while initializing tinyMCE:

```
tinymce.init({/* put readonly setting here */});
```

Answer (score 0):

For the newest version of tinymce (6.x), I found the .getbody() and .setMode() is no longer correct. Use:

```
tinymce.get("xxx").mode.set("readonly | design");
```

or

```
tinymce.activeEditor.mode.set("readonly | design");
```

Instead