# how to make tinymce input read only

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I want to make tinymce input to read only. i have tried with the below code. Please help me with this issue.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#deliberations',
    menubar: false,
    readonly: true, 
    branding: false,
    height: 100,
    max_height: 400,
    theme: 'modern',
    toolbar: false,
                toolbar_items_size: 'small',
                plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak','searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen','insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality','emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc help'],

                toolbar1: 'insert | undo redo |  styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | fullscreen | table',

    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [{
            title: 'Test template 1',
            content: 'Test 1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Test template 2',
            content: 'Test 2'

        }
    ],
    content_css: [

    ]

});
```

Comment: i have tried with readonly : 1 instead of true it is working fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [make readonly/disable tinymce textarea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13881812/make-readonly-disable-tinymce-textarea)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using version 4.x, remove the readonly: true option and try

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.setMode("readonly")
    },
```

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Lugaab/2

Comment: It works for me,  tiny version 5.x

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the TinyMCE docs https://www.tinymce.com/docs-3x/reference/configuration/Configuration3x@readonly/ the `readonly` attribute should be set to '1' not to 'true'.

```
tinymce.init({
    selector: '#deliberations',
    menubar: false,
    readonly: 1, 
    branding: false,
    height: 100,
    max_height: 400,
    theme: 'modern',
    toolbar: false,
                toolbar_items_size: 'small',
                plugins: ['advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview hr anchor pagebreak','searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen','insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality','emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern imagetools codesample toc help'],

                toolbar1: 'insert | undo redo |  styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons | fullscreen | table',

    image_advtab: true,
    templates: [{
            title: 'Test template 1',
            content: 'Test 1'
        },
        {
            title: 'Test template 2',
            content: 'Test 2'

        }
    ],
    content_css: [

    ]

});
```